# Quadratically constrained convex optimization

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, constraint, socp

I have tried to convert the following constraint into SOCP form but can't figure it out. My issue is that whenever I create the norm, the other side has to be square rooted which invalidates the SOCP form.

> The directional parameters ${\boldsymbol w}\in\Bbb R^d$ satisfies the following shaping constraint: $$\boldsymbol w^\top\boldsymbol\Sigma\boldsymbol w+\boldsymbol c^\top\boldsymbol w\le1,$$ where $\boldsymbol\Sigma\in\Bbb R^{d\times d}$ is a **given** symmetric, positive definite matrix and $\boldsymbol c\in\Bbb R^d$ is a **given** vector.

Comment: Btw how do you know Sigma is PSD? Maybe because you know a matrix H such that Sigma=HH'?

Answer (score 8):

For all things convex, Mosek's [modeling cookbook](https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/index.html) and [conic modeling cheatsheet](https://docs.mosek.com/cheatsheets/conic.pdf) have you covered.

In your case, see the section on [convex quadratic sets](https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html#convex-quadratic-sets).

Answer (score 2):

Since $\boldsymbol\Sigma$ is PSD, there exists $\boldsymbol Q$ s.t. $\boldsymbol Q^\top\boldsymbol Q=\boldsymbol \Sigma$ (by Cholesky, or eigendecomposition).

Then $\boldsymbol w^\top\boldsymbol \Sigma\boldsymbol w =\boldsymbol w^\top\boldsymbol Q^\top\boldsymbol Q\boldsymbol w = \|\boldsymbol Q\boldsymbol w\|_2^2.$

Then introduce new variable $y$ as epigraph of $\|\boldsymbol Q\boldsymbol w\|$ as follows:

\begin{align}y+\boldsymbol c^\top\boldsymbol w&=1\tag{linear constraint}\\\|\boldsymbol Q\boldsymbol w\|_2^2&\le y\tag{rotated quadratic cone  constraint}\end{align}

As @mtanneau posted, these modeling tricks(?) are well-explained in the MOSEK tutorial.

If you use MOSEK, you can just directly use rotated quadratic cone to model second constraint.
If you want to convert into second order conic constraints,

\begin{align}&\|\boldsymbol{Qw}\|_{2}^{2} \leq y \\\iff&(\boldsymbol{Qw})^\intercal (\boldsymbol{Qw}) \leq y \\
\iff& (\boldsymbol{Qw})^\intercal (\boldsymbol{Qw})+\frac{(y-1)^2}{4} \leq \frac{(y+1)^2}{4}\\
\iff& \left\|\begin{pmatrix}\boldsymbol{Qw}\\ \frac{y-1}{2} \end{pmatrix}\right\|_{2} \leq \frac{y+1}{2}\end{align}

Hope this is what you're looking for.
*Converting quadratic constraint into soc constraint is well-known tricks, you can find in [https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~nemirovs/LMCOLN2021WithSol.pdf](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/%7Enemirovs/LMCOLN2021WithSol.pdf)

Comment: Shouldn't the 2-norm of $Qw$ be squared?

Comment: @prubin Sure. I had a mistake. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you change $y+c'w\le1$ to $y+c'w = 1$. That is correct and in theory more efficient.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didnt realize making it linear equality is better until now. Thank you :) BTW, can you plz explain or give some references about that efficiency?  Maybe the linear equality can project onto the smaller search space..?

Comment: It follows from the complexity analysis of interior-point methods i.e. the barrier parameter will be smaller with equality.

Comment: Oh i didnt know that. Appreciate the reply!

Comment: Let  v be the barrier parameter. Then let v=(#linear inequalities+2*#quadratic cones) and then in theory the number iterations is sqrt(v)*something.